# How to copy a database table from a disk database to a in "memory" database in R?

Tags: r, sqlite

My question relates to how one can copy over (often referred to as attach) a table from a **disk database** to one that you create in **memory**.

I have seen this done in Python, but am yet to solve it in R.

My following example is this;

I would like to copy over the table *mtcars* from the **disk database .db file called "test.sqlite"**

To a in **memory** database.

```
library(DBI) 

# Create an on disk RSQLite database 

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.sqlite.db") 

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars) 

dbListTables(con)

#so at this point i have the mtcars table in my disk database. 

I would like to now copy it over into a in memory databse;

mem_conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

#stuck here on how to copy over a table
```

Is there a way of copying over the mtcars table from my disk db file to the memory one. The only way i can think is to load the data into an R object then dbWriteTable to the new in memory database.

Although that may not work as the data increases in size.

Thank you in advance, if you got any tips!

For reference using sqlite and R 64 bit

Comment: Why do you say "_Although that may not work as the data increases in size._"? Doesn't the memory database have to "hold" the same amount of data whether it's dbWriteTable or copy from the disk db?

Comment: Since the in-memory database is not accessible outside of R, and I see no mention of quick-import functions in `RSQLite`, I suspect that your only method is to iterate over each of `dbListTables`, select all, and `dbWriteTable` as you suggested. Even using `system("sqlite.exe test.sqlite.db .dump", intern=TRUE)` is prone to the fact that RSQLite does not execute more than one statement (and I find it hard to believe that it would be as fast).

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus - i was assuming that the data would exceed the limits of the RAM available. Howvere on second thought, not sure about where it holds data

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the info - i've never seen the system() function before how does it work in this context? Is .dump copying over the tables?

Comment: It's just an `exec` call to external (non-R) programs. In this case, it's assuming you have the `sqlite3.exe` (windows, others sans `.exe`) binary that can operate on an on-disk database. It knows nothing about an in-memory database, so it is most likely a less-efficient approach ... and since `RSQLite` does not do multi-statement execution, that point is moot atm.

Comment: @r2evans - thanks for clarifying - i'll most likely read it into RAM instead and write it out to the disk database

Comment: @r2evans Just to let you know, I did do this method and it worked normally - but i've encountered some other issues! So thank you for the tips!

Comment: Two steps forward, one step back. Or ... 99 problems, solved with perl/regex, now 100 problems ([xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1171/)).